# Issue with Named Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a project wherein I need to split the string below into multiple groups. I am using Named Regular expression to split into 3 groups:

1. InvoiceNumber
2. Description
3. InvoiceAmount

> ```
> 671217            John Doe v Monica Geller, et al.            $55.50
>                 Pertains To: Joey Tribuiani                                                                               
>                 Firm's File # ABCDEF-123
>                 Claim No# 1237474
> ```

I am using the following regular expression:

```
search = '(?P<InvoiceNumber>\d+)\s+(?P<Description>.*?)\s+(?P<InvoiceAmount>.*?)\s+'
```

Comment: What exactly in the data is the InvoiceNumber, Description and InvoiceAmount?

Comment: InvoiceNumber:671217, InvoiceAmount:$55.50, Description:<Text in the middle>

Comment: Is the description the text before or after the InvoiceNumber?

Comment: Description is after the invoicenumber(it is in the middle of the string)

Comment: You could make the match for the Invoice amount a bit more specific and perhaps match all non empty lines after it as the description `(?P<InvoiceNumber>\d+)\s+(?P<InvoiceAmount>\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<Description>\S.*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*$).*)*)` https://regex101.com/r/14GegZ/1 Or you can make it non greedy and let the dot match a newline to match all that follows including empty lines etc.. https://regex101.com/r/pVjzWH/1

Comment: Wait a second. Is this file format column-oriented? I mean: Is the description part always in the middle of a line? Is the amount always to the very right?

Comment: Could you provide an example with multiple (like 3) entries? Are they in the same file or is each (InvoiceNumber, Description, InvoiceAmount) tuplet in its own file?

Comment: I made tiny change in the string to have all the elements(invoicenumber, invoiceamount, description) start in the same line

Comment: Like this? `(?P<InvoiceNumber>\d+)\s+.*?(?P<Description>\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<InvoiceAmount>.*(?:\r?\n.*)*)` https://regex101.com/r/ly0Zjl/1

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Can you please convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Kiran I have added an answer with a few adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
(?P<InvoiceNumber>\d+)\s+.*?(?P<InvoiceAmount>\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<Description>\S[\S\s]*)
```

That will match

- `(?P<InvoiceNumber>` Named group *InvoiceNumber*

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `)` Close group
- `\s+.*?` Match 1+ whitespace chars, then any char except a whitespace char non greedy
- `(?P<InvoiceAmount>` Named group *InvoiceAmount*

  - `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match the invoice amount with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?P<Description>` Named group *Description*

  - `\S[\S\s]*` Match a non whitespace char so that there at least is a description and all chars that follow
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/59AhY0/1)